# Recover pattern lock of moto g3 marshmallow (unrooted phone) gesture.key (permission denied for removing, backup, copy etc.)

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, unrooting, pattern-lock

I have an unrooted phone.
It has facial recognition so I am able to unlock it and use.
I need to recover my pattern.
I have tried copying, backing up, removing gesture.key but permission is denied( no surprise there) I even tried to give reading/writing permission to gesture.key using chmod but again permission denied.... different errors 100700 etc.

So is there a round about root to open the gesture.key file...

Or where does the number of incorrect pattern store themselves and allow me if I can change its value so that I can guess my pattern. (Less than 500 combinations)

Thanks..
Again the phone isn't unlocked or rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this implementation specifically, but I would expect that pattern is hashed when it is stored (encrypted) - so that even if you could recover it, you would also need to de-crypt it.

Anything dealing with security will be purposely locked down, so users or apps can't abuse the system.

Even if the phone *was* rooted, I think you would still have problems recovering this information.

Comment: Hey booger, it is encrypted with SHA 1 unsalted.